# Cannot click 'Use this file' in wordpress with python selenium

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium

I am trying to upload files automatically with selenium in python to the website.
I succesfully added file to the library but stucked on the point where I the script should click 'Use this file' button:

[screenshot from wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub43n.png)

I tried to use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__wp-uploader-id-0"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button').click()
```

but nothing happens.

tried also use actions:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
Element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__wp-uploader-id-0"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button')
actions.move_to_element(Element).click().perform();
```

but also no luck

Do you  have any idea what else can I try?

Comment: can you share the Url of the webiste? for testing?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Use this file')]").click()
```

Comment: Let me know if this worked. If not possibly will have better ideas

Answer (score 0):

OK it's solved, I had to add time wait until page is loaded fully.

Closing case

Answer (score 0):

if this `//*[@id="__wp-uploader-id-0"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button`

represent a single entity in DOM, you can probably use it with expicit waits :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="__wp-uploader-id-0"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button"))).click()
```

having said that, I would still suggest you to use a relative xpath.